# What kind of trim should go under a deck patio door?

Tags: deck, trim, siding

So an inspection on my brother's house revealed that it has been missing any kind of trim under the patio door that goes out to the deck -- possibly since it was built (he says he just never noticed it until the inspector pointed it out).  It's kind of funny, because the J channel (whole house is basic vinyl siding) was put around the frame like they were expecting something else (besides siding) to go in this space.  This picture from the inspector should show exactly what I'm talking about:

[image: Image of missing Trim]
He's looking for help this weekend to correct the issue, but I'm not 100% sure what would be the best thing to go there.  I'm sure we could put more j channel in there with a short piece of matching siding -- but I think it would look very odd with the already finished edge going down to the deck level.  I was thinking about trying to get a properly sized piece of that white PVC trim stuff from Home Depot which is pretty much just a synthetic board and screwing it in place, but I wonder if there would be issues with that in the winter.

My only real experience with exteriors is putting up basic vinyl siding, so I thought this would be a good place to ask what the proper way to handle this is.  Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Before you do anything, fix that weather wrap.

Comment: Why would you not just take a piece of similar vinyl siding and nail, then caulk, into place? You could rip the height down if you had to.